# AJAX button not submitting and not going through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue where my Ajax code doesn't go through .. As if the functions is empty.
I clicked submit , nothing happens ..

My HTML code :

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="contactForm" >
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit"></input>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'success') {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is Incorrect.');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</head>
```

My check.php:

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $status = 'success'
} else {
    $status = 'failed';
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));

?>
```

When i click submit , it just do nothing..
i want the error to pop up.

Is there anything i missed?

Comment: Because there is a script error caused by an invalid closure. Check the brackets after `else if` which is incorrect and the "success" callback is missing a `:`

Comment: name="submit" is a no no.

Comment: @MartyMcKeever , then if i want to call isset post then i'll be needing it ? no?

Comment: @JayVicious probably not related to your issue, but an input name=submit can and usually will break the form.submit() function. 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp
YMMV w JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the options you're passing into the ajax call are properly cased.  Example: datatype needs to become dataType, and beforesend needs to become beforeSend.

Here is the reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: But if i want to invoke the function from a php and then send to ajax to submit , use datatype??cause i read another stackoverflow if json good for using get function

Comment: I was only referencing your lack of capitalizing the letters that needed to be capitalized.  datatype just needed to have a capital T so that it would be dataType.

Comment: When i changed the value it actually does nothing , back to tier 1..but when i change to datatype, it works.

Comment: Do me a favor please and take out the datatype section from your code completely and see if it still works.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are misplaced and you are missing a `:` for "success" callback. See fixed code below,

And the case too as mentioned in the other answer here..

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'check.php',
        beforeSend: function () {},
        //     v--- missing :
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is correct.');
            } else if (data.status !== 'success') {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is wrong.');
            }
        } // this was misplaced in the line below in your code
    }); // this was misplaced in the line above in your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks that really fix it but now everything returns me if the data type is not success a.k.a the email address entered is wrong.. i put empty and with digits also returns me that value.

Comment: Now actually nothing happens with i change the datatype to dataType

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug using the dev tools of Firefox or Chrome.

On Chrome's DevTools for example:

- Debug [Javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) with the source option. Or you cold add some `console.log()` inside your .submit() function to make sure that the event handler is triggering.
- Use the [network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) to make sure the ajax call is being made and check which response you get from server.
- Last but not less important, check the [console tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) for Javascript errors to see if another script throws an error before the excecution of your script.

With these techniques, you can identify what could be wrong and see how could could solve it.

Comment: Now it's working for me , but a quick question.. why i keep on having two pop up with the same message?

Comment: It could be that for some reason, the alert() is being called twice, try to add a "console log('called');" function to check. If that is happening, you will see 2 messages on the console of the DevTools.